# How do I setup HTTPS with a Single Instance Elastic Load Balancer for node.js?

Tags: node.js, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a `.ebextensions/https-instance-securitygroup.config`:

```
Resources:
  sslSecurityGroupIngress: 
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
    Properties:
      GroupId: {"Fn::GetAtt" : ["AWSEBSecurityGroup", "GroupId"]}
      IpProtocol: tcp
      ToPort: 443
      FromPort: 443
      CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```

However, my URL isn't `https`. How can I configure it to be `https`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to create a file called "securelistener-alb.config" with the follwoing and add it to your extentions folder:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elb:listener:443:
    SSLCertificateId: arn:aws:acm:us-east-2:1234567890123:certificate/####################################
    ListenerProtocol: HTTPS
    InstancePort: 80
```

Comment: What's the `SSLCertificateId`?

Comment: Tried it - no dice

Comment: The SSLCertificateID is the arn of your certificate that is registered with AWS certificate manager. In order to add https will need to create a certificate. Do you have one registered?

Comment: Check this link out: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-https-configuration/

Comment: Yes - I made, registered and verified an AWS SSL cert

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-ssl-load-balancer/

Comment: Did you add the arn of your cert in your config file?

Comment: Yup. Copied and pasted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215248/discussion-between-tony-and-shamoon).